# Как решить проблему с модальными окнами?

Tags: javascript, css

Нашла [вот такой вот](https://codyhouse.co/gem/morphing-modal-window/) интересный эффект для модального окна и хочу использовать его в проекте.
Задача такая: на странице этот эффект будет использоваться для модальных окон, а так же для меню "гамбургера".
Но если для модальных окон все отлично подходит (независимо от того, сколько кнопок будет располагаться на странице, у каждой будет своя модалка), то с меню "гамбургером" возникли проблемы.

Путем тыкания, поняла, что вызов модалки вместе с эффектом реагирует на `data-type="modal-trigger"`. Оригинальный скрипт написан так, что `data-type` присваивается кнопки, при нажатии на которую окно открывается, а закрывается крестиком, который "существует" отдельно внутри модалки. И с гамбургером проблема заключается в том, что он трансформируется в крестик при открытии модального окна, и чтобы это окно закрыть, нужно нажать на этот крестик, модальное окно закроется, и он обратно трансформируется в гамбургер. Но скрипт на этот самописный крестик не реагирует.

Я пробовала убирать `data-type`, если гамбургеру присваивается класс `.open`, но не сработало. Подставляла вместо `data-type` класс, пробовала ковыряться в css, но все тщетно.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  //trigger the animation - open modal window
  $('[data-type="modal-trigger"]').on('click', function() {
    var actionBtn = $(this),
      scaleValue = retrieveScale(actionBtn.next('.cd-modal-bg'));

    actionBtn.addClass('to-circle');
    actionBtn.next('.cd-modal-bg').addClass('is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
      animateLayer(actionBtn.next('.cd-modal-bg'), scaleValue, true);
    });

    //if browser doesn't support transitions...
    if (actionBtn.parents('.no-csstransitions').length > 0) animateLayer(actionBtn.next('.cd-modal-bg'), scaleValue, true);
  });

  $(".toggle").click(function() {
    $(".toggle").toggleClass("toggle-open");
  });

});

//trigger the animation - close modal window
$('.cd-section .cd-modal-close, .cd-section .toggle').on('click', function() {
  closeModal();
});
$(document).keyup(function(event) {
  if (event.which == '27') closeModal();
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
  //on window resize - update cover layer dimention and position
  if ($('.cd-section.modal-is-visible').length > 0) window.requestAnimationFrame(updateLayer);
});

function retrieveScale(btn) {
  var btnRadius = btn.width() / 2,
    left = btn.offset().left + btnRadius,
    top = btn.offset().top + btnRadius - $(window).scrollTop(),
    scale = scaleValue(top, left, btnRadius, $(window).height(), $(window).width());

  btn.css('position', 'fixed').velocity({
    top: top - btnRadius,
    left: left - btnRadius,
    translateX: 0,
  }, 0);

  return scale;
}

function scaleValue(topValue, leftValue, radiusValue, windowW, windowH) {
  var maxDistHor = (leftValue > windowW / 2) ? leftValue : (windowW - leftValue),
    maxDistVert = (topValue > windowH / 2) ? topValue : (windowH - topValue);
  return Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(maxDistHor, 2) + Math.pow(maxDistVert, 2)) / radiusValue);
}

function animateLayer(layer, scaleVal, bool) {
  layer.velocity({
    scale: scaleVal
  }, 400, function() {
    $('body').toggleClass('overflow-hidden', bool);
    (bool) ? layer.parents('.cd-section').addClass('modal-is-visible').end().off('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend'): layer.removeClass('is-visible').removeAttr('style').siblings('[data-type="modal-trigger"]').removeClass('to-circle');
  });
}

function updateLayer() {
  var layer = $('.cd-section.modal-is-visible').find('.cd-modal-bg'),
    layerRadius = layer.width() / 2,
    layerTop = layer.siblings('.btn').offset().top + layerRadius - $(window).scrollTop(),
    layerLeft = layer.siblings('.btn').offset().left + layerRadius,
    scale = scaleValue(layerTop, layerLeft, layerRadius, $(window).height(), $(window).width());

  layer.velocity({
    top: layerTop - layerRadius,
    left: layerLeft - layerRadius,
    scale: scale,
  }, 0);
}

function closeModal() {
  var section = $('.cd-section.modal-is-visible');
  section.removeClass('modal-is-visible').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
    animateLayer(section.find('.cd-modal-bg'), 1, false);
  });
  //if browser doesn't support transitions...
  if (section.parents('.no-csstransitions').length > 0) animateLayer(section.find('.cd-modal-bg'), 1, false);
}
```

```css
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */

*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}
body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #34383c;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
body.overflow-hidden {
  /* used when modal is visible */
  overflow: hidden;
}
a {
  color: #03bb91;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* -------------------------------- 

Main Components 

-------------------------------- */

header {
  position: relative;
  height: 160px;
  line-height: 160px;
}
header h1 {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  text-align: center;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  header {
    height: 240px;
    line-height: 240px;
  }
  header h1 {
    font-size: 3.2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}
.cd-section {
  padding: 2em 5%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #03bb91;
}
.cd-section p {
  margin: 2em 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
  color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-section {
    padding: 4em 10%;
  }
  .cd-section p {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 2;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-section {
    padding: 4em 20%;
  }
}
.cd-modal {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s 0s, z-index 0s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s 0s, z-index 0s 0.3s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s 0s, z-index 0s 0.3s;
}
.cd-modal::after {
  /* gradient overlay at bottom of modal window */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: transparent;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #34383c, rgba(52, 56, 60, 0));
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #34383c, rgba(52, 56, 60, 0));
}
.cd-modal .cd-modal-content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3em 5%;
  text-align: left;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.cd-modal p {
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 1.6;
  margin: 2em 0;
}
.modal-is-visible .cd-modal {
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0s, opacity 0.3s 0s, z-index 0s 0s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0s, opacity 0.3s 0s, z-index 0s 0s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0s, opacity 0.3s 0s, z-index 0s 0s;
}
.modal-is-visible .cd-modal .cd-modal-content {
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-modal .cd-modal-content {
    padding: 4em 10%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .cd-modal .cd-modal-content {
    padding: 6em 20%;
  }
  .cd-modal p {
    font-size: 2rem;
    line-height: 2;
  }
}
.cd-modal-action {
  position: relative;
}
.cd-modal-action .btn,
.cd-modal-action .cd-modal-bg {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: #34383c;
}
.cd-modal-action .btn {
  width: 12.5em;
  border-radius: 5em;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 4em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s 0.3s, width 0.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s 0.3s, width 0.3s 0s;
  transition: color 0.2s 0.3s, width 0.3s 0s;
}
.cd-modal-action .btn.to-circle {
  width: 4em;
  color: transparent;
  -webkit-transition: color 0.2s 0s, width 0.3s 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: color 0.2s 0s, width 0.3s 0.2s;
  transition: color 0.2s 0s, width 0.3s 0.2s;
}
.cd-modal-action .cd-modal-bg {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: 4em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-2em);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-2em);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-2em);
  -o-transform: translateX(-2em);
  transform: translateX(-2em);
  -webkit-transition: visibility 0s 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: visibility 0s 0.5s;
  transition: visibility 0s 0.5s;
}
.cd-modal-action .cd-modal-bg.is-visible {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
.cd-modal-close {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20px;
  right: 5%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) url(../img/cd-icon-close.svg) no-repeat center center;
  /* image replacement */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
  -moz-transform: scale(0);
  -ms-transform: scale(0);
  -o-transform: scale(0);
  transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s 0s;
  transition: transform 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0.3s, opacity 0.3s 0s;
}
.no-touch .cd-modal-close:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.modal-is-visible .cd-modal-close {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s, opacity 0.3s 0s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s, opacity 0.3s 0s;
  transition: transform 0.3s 0s, visibility 0s 0s, opacity 0.3s 0s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  -o-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-modal-close {
    top: 70px;
  }
}
.toggle {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 27px;
  height: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  z-index: 999999;
  position: absolute;
  /* right: 0; */
}
.toggle span {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}
.toggle span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 5px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.toggle span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 14px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.toggle span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 23px;
  -webkit-transform-origin: left center;
  transform-origin: left center;
}
.toggle.toggle-open span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  top: 3px;
  left: 4px;
}
.toggle.toggle-open span:nth-child(2) {
  width: 0%;
  opacity: 0;
}
.toggle.toggle-open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 23px;
  left: 4px;
}
.menu {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.4.1/velocity.min.js"></script>
<section class="cd-section">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non ipsum repudiandae sequi ut optio reiciendis consectetur, cum, a provident, iusto quod esse, perferendis iure iste! Quidem itaque, exercitationem aliquam, mollitia recusandae repellat dolores
    quibusdam minima quae reprehenderit ut, reiciendis officia.
  </p>

  <div class="cd-modal-action">
    <a href="#0" class="btn" data-type="modal-trigger">Fire Modal Window</a>
    <span class="cd-modal-bg"></span>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-modal-action -->

  <div class="cd-modal">
    <div class="cd-modal-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad modi repellendus, optio eveniet eligendi molestiae? Fugiat, temporibus! A rerum pariatur neque laborum earum, illum voluptatibus eum voluptatem fugiat, porro animi tempora? Sit harum nulla,
        nesciunt molestias, iusto aliquam aperiam est qui possimus reprehenderit ipsam ea aut assumenda inventore iste! Animi quaerat facere repudiandae earum quisquam accusamus tempora, delectus nesciunt, provident quae aliquam, voluptatum beatae quis
        similique in maiores repellat eligendi voluptas veniam optio illum vero! Eius, dignissimos esse eligendi veniam.
      </p>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad modi repellendus, optio eveniet eligendi molestiae? Fugiat, temporibus! A rerum pariatur neque laborum earum, illum voluptatibus eum voluptatem fugiat, porro animi tempora? Sit harum nulla,
        nesciunt molestias, iusto aliquam aperiam est qui possimus reprehenderit ipsam ea aut assumenda inventore iste! Animi quaerat facere repudiandae earum quisquam accusamus tempora, delectus nesciunt, provident quae aliquam, voluptatum beatae quis
        similique in maiores repellat eligendi voluptas veniam optio illum vero! Eius, dignissimos esse eligendi veniam.
      </p>

      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad modi repellendus, optio eveniet eligendi molestiae? Fugiat, temporibus! A rerum pariatur neque laborum earum, illum voluptatibus eum voluptatem fugiat, porro animi tempora? Sit harum nulla,
        nesciunt molestias, iusto aliquam aperiam est qui possimus reprehenderit ipsam ea aut assumenda inventore iste! Animi quaerat facere repudiandae earum quisquam accusamus tempora, delectus nesciunt, provident quae aliquam, voluptatum beatae quis
        similique in maiores repellat eligendi voluptas veniam optio illum vero! Eius, dignissimos esse eligendi veniam.
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- cd-modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- cd-modal -->

  <a href="#0" class="cd-modal-close">Close</a>
</section>
<!-- .cd-section -->


<section class="cd-section">

  <div class="cd-modal-action menu">
    <a href="#0" class="toggle" data-type="modal-trigger"><span></span>
   <span></span>
   <span></span></a>
    <span class="cd-modal-bg"></span>
  </div>
  <!-- cd-modal-action -->

  <div class="cd-modal">
    <div class="cd-modal-content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad modi repellendus, optio eveniet eligendi molestiae? Fugiat, temporibus! A rerum pariatur neque laborum earum, illum voluptatibus eum voluptatem fugiat, porro animi tempora? Sit harum nulla,
        nesciunt molestias, iusto aliquam aperiam est qui possimus reprehenderit ipsam ea aut assumenda inventore iste! Animi quaerat facere repudiandae earum quisquam accusamus tempora, delectus nesciunt, provident quae aliquam, voluptatum beatae quis
        similique in maiores repellat eligendi voluptas veniam optio illum vero! Eius, dignissimos esse eligendi veniam.
      </p>
    </div>
    <!-- cd-modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- cd-modal -->

  <a href="#0" class="cd-modal-close">Close</a>
</section>
<!-- .cd-section -->
```

Comment: А вы можете, пожалуйста, сделать ваш код запускаемым? И если есть возможность упростить ваш код до той части с которой проблемы.

Comment: да ну самое простое сделать две кнопки. Нажали на иконку открыть, окно открылось, а самой иконке установили hidden, что сделало её невидимым и тем самым видимым кнопку с крестиком находящимся под кнопкой открыть.

Comment: А вы этот код случайно не в посте Wordpress размещаете? Там работать не будет потому что WP меняет data-type на data - type.